# How to get child in xml?

Tags: javascript, xml, web

I have xml file and html and javascrips, and I want to show all elements with tag name "prece", but only with parent tag name "book". How can I do that?
Hier is xml file:

```
<BOOK>
<PRECE>
<NOSAUKUMS></NOSAUKUMS>
<CENA></CENA>
<APRAKSTS></APRAKSTS>
<BILDE></BILDE>
</PRECE>
<PRECE>
<NOSAUKUMS></NOSAUKUMS>
<CENA></CENA>
<APRAKSTS></APRAKSTS>
<BILDE></BILDE>
</PRECE>
</BOOK>
<VIDEO>
<PRECE>
<NOSAUKUMS></NOSAUKUMS>
<CENA></CENA>
<APRAKSTS></APRAKSTS>
<BILDE></BILDE>
</PRECE>
<PRECE>
<NOSAUKUMS></NOSAUKUMS>
<CENA></CENA>
<APRAKSTS></APRAKSTS>
<BILDE></BILDE>
</PRECE>
</VIDEO>
```

And hier is javascript:

```
  function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table = "";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("BOOK");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      table += "<div class='prece'><img class='xmlImage' src='" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("BILDE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "'><div class='nosaukums'>" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("NOSAUKUMS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</div><div class='cena'>&euro;" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("CENA")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</div>" +
        //x[i].getElementsByTagName("APRAKSTS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "<button>Pievienot grozam</button></div>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
  }
```

Comment: select for each book all the pierce tags if the length of the array returned is 1 or more continue doing what your doing else skip it

Comment: Could you please write for me that line

Comment: there i didn;t test it but it should work

Comment: Doesn't work :(

Comment: what does the log say?

Comment: Why not access `PRECE` elements first and then filter them based on their parent name ? Like: `const elements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PRECE");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].parentElement.localName == "BOOK") {
    // ...
  }
}
`

Comment: there is more than one prece per book though

Comment: Yess, thank you so much. At the beginning it didn't work, but I forgot to change x[i] to elements[i] and everything works. Thank you <3

Comment: glad to hear!:)